# Error while trying to create an angular component

Tags: node.js, angular6

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyzCv.png)I am getting 'type is not defined' error while trying to create an angular component

commands tried :

```
              ng g c componentname

             ng generate component componentname
```

Comment: can you share some more details like how you generated angular project and have you installed angular CLI?

Comment: angular project generated command: ng new myApp      angular client installed command :npm install -g @angular/cli

Comment: yes i have installed angular client in my system

Comment: from which directory are you running ng g c command? And can you check angular versions using ng --version? Try running the command on the root project directory first and from a different shell as well like CMD, powershell or visual studio code

Comment: Please put a screenshot of the exact error

Comment: Angular CLI: 9.1.1
Node: 12.16.2
OS: win32 x64

Angular:
...
Ivy Workspace:

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.901.1
@angular-devkit/core         9.1.1
@angular-devkit/schematics   9.1.1
@angular/cli                 9.1.1
@schematics/angular          9.1.1
@schematics/update           0.901.1
rxjs                         6.5.4                                                                                           
 this is the angular version

Comment: error is a simple red line telling "type is not deffined"

Comment: and iam running the command on the root project directory